# Cannot install react native fs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm

I'm trying to install the react native file system module using the following command:

```
npm i react-native-fs
```

Once I install the module and try to just import it I get this error:

```
cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rnfsfiletyperegular')
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "loginApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native run-windows",
    "test": "jest",
    "windows": "react-native run-windows"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "mdb-reader": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.7",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-windows": "0.72.20",
    "stream": "^0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-config": "^0.76.8",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

I appreciate your help!